# JQuery Treeview with Tri-State Checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, treeview, checkbox, yui

Does anyone know of a JQuery solution for treeview with tristate checkboxes? I'm looking at using YUI, but have more experience in JQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[jsTree](http://www.jstree.com/) has this as well, [you can see a demo here](http://www.jstree.com/demo/checkbox), the setup/call itself is pretty easy:

```
$("#myTree").tree({ 
   ui : { theme_name : "checkbox" }, 
   plugins : { checkbox : { } }
});
```

There's also the simpler [jQuery Checkbox tree Plugin](http://floatmargin.com/2009/jquery-checkbox-tree-plugin-new-and-improved/) ([demo here](http://floatmargin.com/demos/checkboxtree/checkboxtree.html)), but it doesn't do tri-state, just throwing it out there as a very lightweight option though.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look here: 
http://www.terminally-incoherent.com/blog/2008/03/24/3-value-checkbox-with-jquery/

It is a tri-state checkbox but I think you can adapt it to a treeview.